# identify duplicate calls within same call stack - java

Tags: java, performance, methods, parameters, duplicates

Need some help regarding performance improvement in Java.  Is there any way to understand whether there are any duplicate method calls(same method with same parameter values) within the same call stack.

To keep it more clear:

`MethodA(int A)` - returns int B.

Lets say that this method gets invoked from number of other classes and from other modules. In a single long chained transaction if this method gets called multiple times with same input parameters `MethodA(1)` it reduces the performance.  Instead I believe that the better approach must be to use the result from first invocation every time instead of invoking `MethodA(1)` every time.

Is it is possible to identify the duplicate calls other than manually analyzing everything.  For now I am trying to cache locally the results so avoiding the calls to the same method with same query parameter. But still trying to identify the duplicate calls so that can narrow it down to the root cause.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to optimize code? In that case I would strongly advise to use a [profiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) first that will indicate the hotspots where optimization makes most sense.

Comment: Thank you for your time Rutte.  We use dynatrace but that identifies how many number of calls are made for each method, but not exactly whether duplicate calls are made within single transaction. Is there is something which am missing and can be achieved using profiler.

Comment: I think you will waste more time on analysis compared to just making the method cacheable. For the analysis, I'd log invocations and then group log statements to see if some groups have many entries.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be sure that given method has no side effects, as in every invocation with a given value of the parameter will **always** return the same value.

You can use CGLIB to create method/class proxy and then use any cache implementation, return known or cached results for same input.

Example (reference https://gist.github.com/ksauzz/1563486) :

```
List<String> proxyAry = (List<String>)Enhancer
.create(TargetClass.class, new MyInvocationHandler(ary));

static class MyInvocationHandler implements MethodInterceptor {

    private TargetClass<String> ary;

    public MyInvocationHandler(TargetClass<String> ary) {
        this.ary = ary;
    }

    @Override
    public Object intercept(Object obj, Method method, Object[] args, MethodProxy proxy) throws Throwable {
        if (isFouthGet(method, args)) {
            return "Bow!!";
        }
        return proxy.invoke(ary, args);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you amitmah.  Yes, everytime the return value will be same.  But I am trying to find out what are all the caller methods that potentially may call this method with same parameters.  So it would be helpful in finding out a way to avoid duplicate calls instead of caching and retrieving from cache.